# A nice program to show system temperatures in a dock bar?

Tags: windows, display, temperature, dock

Is there any nice application that shows the system temperatures in a somekind of dockbar or similar? (Windows)

Preferably with this features:

- Real temperature (I've tried programs that shows wrong temperatures)
- CPU temp
- Motherboard temp
- VGA temp
- Lightweight

I've been searching but couldn't find anything like that.

If not, **how do you monitor your system temperatures?** Maybe some app that doesn't show me the temps all  the time, but will alert me on reaching temp. thresholds (custom configured).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all of my machines (that support it), I use [CoreTemp32](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/).

It's billed as `...is a compact, no fuss, small footprint, yet powerful program to monitor processor temperature and other vital information.`

One of it's features is "overheat protection" that is, you can configure it so once it reaches a certain temp it can create a popup in the tray icon, Shut down the machine or run a program. It seems to just monitor CPU temps however, but for a general overview of what the system is doing you cant really beat it.

[image]

(ignore the high Max temp above, my laptop tends to run hot when gaming).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what dock-bar program you use. If you are simply asking about temperature monitoring, there are plenty of programs that can do it.

Personally, I use [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to see my CPU temp in the notification area (aka tray) and [ATI Tray Tools](http://downloads.guru3d.com/download.php) to see my video-card temp in the tray. Both are configurable and also allow controlling the fans. They can do all kinds of things when temperatures reach a limit like adjusting fans, beeping, showing alerts, sending emails, and so on. [RivaTuner] can also monitor video-card temperatures and supports Nvidia as well.

As for wrong temperatures, you need to make sure that the correct temperature has the correct label. They do not always apply the correct label (eg the board temp is labeled CPU, etc.), so you need to edit the labels as required.

www.guru3d.com/category/rivatuner/

For RocketDock specifically, there do not seem to be many temperature monitor addons. This steam-punk themed one is the only one I could find. `rocketdock.com/addon/misc/39639`

Comment: I use RocketDock. I have an nVidia card. I'll try SpeedFan and RivaTuner.

Comment: I use about the same thing. with "Speedfan Meter" gadget, and "gpu observer" gadget on the desktop. I wouldnt say i like it, but its there :-) "Rainmeter" is sweet, but I didnt want to get into the days of configuring/skinning it just yet.  MBM5 (motherboard monitor) i would still rather have, but it needs more work to get going in win7